# Tagging a box considering the value of its content

Tags: python, nested-loops

I was wondering if there is a more pythonian way to tag a box considering the value of the contents. I have a (supposedly) working code, that seems efficient (dealing with 23 million lines in less of the blink of an eye). Still, it seems a bit convoluted.

Consider I have a list such as:

```
d=[['ref1', 'apple', '500'],['ref1','orange', '10.7']...['refn','apple','30.5']]
```

this list is sorted by "reference" (d[i][0]). Refs are arbitrary, and in an unknown (yet large) number (simplified to ref1... refn). There is also an unknown number of fruit types. The number following each ref represents the value that fruit is worth in that box.

So I start by getting the unique box reference and fruit types in a sorted manner:

```
ru=[0 for i in range(len(d))]
for i in range(len(d)):
    ru[i]=d[i][0]
ru=sorted(list(set(ru))) # unique references sorted
    
uu=[0 for i in range(len(d))]
    for i in range(len(d)): uu[i]=d[i][1]
uu=sorted(list(set(uu))) # unique fruit types sorted
```

I then create a list, size of fruit types times box reference numbers, adding two fields, one for the reference, another for the fruit type tagging that box:

```
ru_uu=[[0 for i in range(len(uu)+2)] for i in range(len(ru))]
```

I start populating references in the first position, corresponding to the box reference.

```
for i in range(len(ru)):
    ru_uu[i][0]=ru[i]
```

And I now loop over each matrix as follows:

```
 k=0                              # given all matrix are sorted, this will aid the lookup process with a break sentence
    for m in range(len(ru_uu)):   # I loop through the full "mixed matrix", one line per box reference, one column per fruit type plus a column for the reference and another where to store the most valuable fruit in that box...
        refcat1=ru_uu[m][0]       # ... remembering the box reference
        for i in range(k,len(d)): # I now loop through the list of lists (boxex)...
            refcat2=d[i][0]       #so every time a box has the same reference, .... 
            if refcat1==refcat2:
                for j in range(len(uu)): # .... I test if there is a match with any of my fruit types....
                    if uu[j] in d[i]:
                        ru_uu[m][(uu.index(d[i][1])+1)]=ru_uu[m][(uu.index(d[i][1])+1)]+int(100*float(d[i][2])) # and if there is, I accumulate the value in a position matching the unique fruit reference+1 because the first position is the box reference.
            else: 
                k=i # if I find a reference not matching, I have finished evaluating that box, so i know I have to loop over a new box that will start there where the no match occurs
                break
```

The final step is to pick up the most valuable fruit and tag the box with it:

```
t=len(ru_uu[0])
for i in range(len(ru_uu)): 
    ru_uu[i][t-1]=uu[(ru_uu[i].index(max(ru_uu[i][1:t-1])))-1] # gets the max value of the summed values of the different fruits a box might contain.
```

This way, i will end with a list such as:

```
ru_uu=['ref1',0,0....12....60...'pineapple'] #where I have the box reference, the accumulated values for each fruit type that particular box contains, and the fruit that has more value within the box.
```

An issue would be if I have two fruit types worth the same. I'd like to prioritize somehow, later on.

I accumulate values in int, because floats causes some issues.

So... is there a more "pythonic" cleaner way for this task or does it look fine? I am new to python and this looks more like an old style code.

Sample input:

```
84353225683,apple,4491
84353235683,pineapple,5017
83337135683,watermelon,5747
84353245683,apple,5017
84353255683,apple,5017
84353255683,Avocado,5017
84353255683,Bilberry,4491
84353255683,apple,2683
82356115683,apple,3683
82356125683,apple,2441
```

...

Sample unique fruits:

```
['Apricot', 'Avocado', 'Bilberry', 'Blueberry', 'Breadfruit', 'Canistel', 'apple', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'watermelon']
```

Sample output:

```
['82356135683', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3693, 0, 0, 0, 'apple'],
['82356145683', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3269, 0, 0, 0, 'apple'],
['82356155683', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1060, 0, 0, 'orange'],
['82356165683', 4912, 0, 0, 0, 5903, 5830, 8099, 0, 0, 0, 'apple'],
['83337135683', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5747, 'watermelon'],
```

...

Comment: Could you please just add small snippets of a sample input and the desired output? The Sorting could be made easier by using the `key` argument. However, I did not figure out what's required after that. So a sample in- and output would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you Albert for your fast reply. I've edited the question adding some sample input and sample output. I hope it is clearer now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're allowed to use numpy but if you are then this should work. This assumes you have an input string like:

```
84353225683,apple,4491
84353235683,pineapple,5017
83337135683,watermelon,5747
84353245683,apple,5017
84353255683,apple,5017
84353255683,Avocado,5017
84353255683,Bilberry,4491
84353255683,apple,2683
82356115683,apple,3683
82356125683,apple,2441
```

called a and nothing else. It should be faster then your current solution:

```
a = a.strip().split("\n")
a = np.array(list(map(lambda s: s.split(","), a)))

refs = np.sort(np.unique(a[:, 0]))
fruits = np.sort(np.unique(a[:, 1]))
result = np.zeros((len(refs), len(fruits)+2), dtype=object)


for i in range(len(refs)):
    for j in range(len(fruits)):
        result[i][j + 1] = np.sum((a[(a[:, 0] == refs[i]) & (a[:, 1] == fruits[j])][:, 2]).astype(int))

result[:, -1] = fruits[np.argmax(result, axis=1) - 1]
result[:, 0] = refs
```

Comment: That is certainly a much clearer, and understandable code. However, for very large datasets it is slower than the multiloop. And I am not fully sure why... Could it be that the part where a[:,0]==refs[i] & (a[:,1]==fruits[j] implies an evaluation over the full length of the data whereas the multiloop only evaluates each line one time? I am really learning here, thank you very much. For smaller sets of data I will be using this true/false matrix for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out a faster, cleaner way with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Let *d* be the list, size (10,3) such as the sample data input; creating a dataframe *d0* from it would be:

```
d0=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['ref', 'fruit', 'euro'])
```

then just a line is enough to reach the item of the quest by providing a sum in a grouped series:

```
d1 = d0.groupby(['ref','fruit'])['euro'].sum().reset_index()
```

This method is at least x4 times faster than the original loop version (as roughly tested on a randomized (10e7x3) list; more than x12 times faster than the np version [which was interrupted before finishing]) and a universe simpler to read and understand. Time to decide if populating with 0 makes much sense now...